# Format Date as 01:00a , 05:00p

Tags: jstl

I am using jstl tag `<fmt:formatDate value="${attdDate}" pattern="hh:mma" />` to convert my dateObj into particular time format.

**Time format required is** : **01:00a , 04:30p** but I always end up getting **01:00AM , 04:30PM**.

Is there any way by which I get the time above mentioned format.

Thanks

Comment: Create your own JSP tag or function that formats the date and then replaces AM by a and PM by p. Or, if it's a one-time thing, store the formatted date into a var, and use fn:replace: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html

Comment: @JBNizet.. Thanks for the reply....I know I cannot use <fmt:formatDate /> to get the required format. fn:replace can definitely work but can we do it via joda:format instead.